# Accepting fix patterned user input with string containing alphanumeric characters

Tags: bash, shell

I’m new to shell script, I am trying to make a shell script that accepts user input in following pattern : alphabet.alphabet 
(No numbers , no space, no uppercase, and strictly one “.” In between alphabets)
Eg: abc.pqr
I tried following code

```
If [[ “$1” =~ ^[a-z\.\a-z]+$ ]]; then echo “matched” else “not matched” fi
```

But it accepts “.pqr” and “abc.”Pattern also.
I don’t know what am I doing wrong. 
Can anyone explain please. ^ ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your regex to accomplish what you are trying to do using the POSIX bracket expressions as below.

```
regex='^[[:lower:]]{1,}\.[[:lower:]]{1,}$'
```

Also you don't need to quote the L.H.S operand of the regex operator, doing below should be fine

```
[[ $1 =~ $regex ]]
```

Notice also the incorrect usage of incorrect unicode double-quoted `“` which is not treated by the shell properly. It should have been `"`

See the regular expression match at https://regex101.com/r/be72FB/1

---

The problem with why your regex didn't match is two-fold

1. Inappropriate 2<sup>nd</sup>  escape `\` which was in wrong place altogether. Only the `.` needs to be escaped to avoid being treated as a special character.
2. The presence of `.` inside the bracket expression with a trailing `+` means that the `.` can occur any number of times in the search string which is incorrect.